# Release Definition in Azure DevOps and Team Foundation Server plugin for Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I'm following this tutorial from a Microsoft Cloud Advocate to set up Azure DevOps and Jenkins integration: https://medium.com/@bbenz/azure-devops-and-jenkins-in-perfect-harmony-8c92ff980723 .

I'm not able to trigger a new Azure DevOps pipeline release when Jenkins successfully completes a build.

There is **no release definition** available in my Jenkins dropdown menu for the Jenkins Team Foundation Server (TFS) plugin. I have created a Pipeline release in Azure DevOps, FYI.

[image: Screenshot from Jenkins]

In the above mentioned tutorial, there's no mention of setting up a release definition and based on research release definitions are only mentioned in resources from several years ago.

How do I resolve this? The Github repository seems to imply the TFS plugin supports Azure DevOps in its current iteration.

Lastly, not surprisingly, when running the Build on Jenkins I get an error. In this case, a 404: `hudson.plugins.tfs.rm.ReleaseManagementException: Error occurred.%nStatus: 404%nResponse:`

Comment: The tutorial says the following (`Release Pipeline` is the new name for `Release Definition`):
"Next up, we create a release pipeline in Azure DevOps pipelines. In Azure DevOps, navigate to Pipelines > Releases and click new pipeline. Choose a template (I chose empty job for now) and name your pipeline stage."

Comment: Hey @riQQ, thanks for the reply! My thought was the same - that ```Release Pipeline``` would be the new name for Release Definition. However, my Pipeline name doesn't come up in Release Definition drop down menu for the TFS plugin. I have one named SpringBoot-Test.

Comment: How have you configured the scope of the PAT? Can you see the release pipeline using this PAT with the Azure DevOps REST API?

Comment: thanks for trying to help. i resolved the issue and my answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is with the TFS Plugin for Jenkins. I had to update the calls to the Azure DevOps API in the source code because the URL scheme has changed and no one updated the code for the plugin.

To anyone reading this, just know the TFS Plugin is not maintained.

Comment: This PR illustrates the issue: https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/pull/224

Comment: It goes beyond the collection URL. It's for releases too.